# How do people get 2000+ CP Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm currently a level 12 player of Pokemon Go.
The highest level CP Pokemon I've caught so far is CP 468.
However, I often see that the gyms are populated with Pokemon with CP 2000+.

How do people get such high CP Pokemon?
Is it because they spent a lot of stardust and candies powering up their Pokemon?

Comment: As you level up, the CP of pokemon you catch rises.

Comment: A google search of literally "2000 cp pokemon go" reveals so many results that answer your question it's not even funny. Please try and get answers to simple questions before posting.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud this is now the first Google result for "2000 cp pokemon go"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### High-CP pokémon are owned by high-level trainers

The levels of pokémon that you can have is limited by your trainer level.<sup>†</sup> Level and CP don't match exactly, but level is a major factor that goes into calculating a pokémon's CP. Higher CP means that a pokémon is higher level.

This limit from *your* trainer level means that the best wild pokémon you meet will always have a lower pokémon level than the best pokémon a higher-level trainer can meet, so that you're even able to own them if you catch them. As your trainer level increases, you will meet more wild pokémon of higher levels (and therefore higher CPs). You will also be able to power up your existing pokémon to higher levels/CP when your trainer level is higher.

So the reason you see all these high-CP pokémon in gyms is because those players have high trainer levels that allow for catching higher-CP pokémon and powering up them up to even higher CPs. When your level gets up into the high 20s, you'll have CP 2000+ pokémon too.

---

<sup>† The game won't show you a pokémon's actual level number, but instead it shows you that arc behind each caught pokémon. The very end of the arc is the maximum pokémon level that you can have, and where the dot is, is the level of that pokémon. Each time you power up a pokémon, it goes up 0.5 levels.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

it takes to about level 25 to get 2000+ CP Pokemon. We Have 7 2000+ Pokemon at level 28. and we got are first one at level 24. exeggute is a good evolution

Comment: No, this is incorrect. I'm level 18 with a CP 2174 Vaporeon